# R: Which apply function be used to apply through a matrix and a vector?

Tags: r

BI am trying the divide each column of the matrix `dataa` by the one of the elements in the vector `mu_i`.

```
> dput(dataa)
structure(list(`175` = c(2.04, 1.91, 2, 1.92, 1.85, 1.96, 1.88, 
1.9), `194` = c(1.66, 1.71, 1.42, 1.76, 1.66, 1.61, 1.55, 1.66
), `213` = c(1.53, 1.54, 1.38, 1.31, 1.35, 1.27, 1.26, 1.38), 
    `231` = c(1.15, 1.22, 1.17, 1.16, 1.21, 1.28, 1.17, 0), `250` = c(1.26, 
    0.83, 1.08, 1.02, 1.09, 1.06, 0, 0)), .Names = c("175", "194", 
"213", "231", "250"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(mu_i)
c(1.9325, 1.62875, 1.3775, 1.19428571428571, 1.05666666666667
)
```

Essentially, what I want is `dataa[,i] / mu_i[i]` and iterate `i` from 1 to 5. (i.e. $i^th$ column of `dataa` divided by the $i^th$ element in `mu_i`)I know that I can do this a for loop but I would like to know how this can be done using `apply` function ?

UPDATE:
I appreciated all your answers. I just want to ask one more question:
I was trying to do this using the mapply function like this
`mapply(function(d,m,i)d[,i] - m[i],dataa,mu_i,seq_along(mu_i) )`. I don't understand why this failed. For some reasons, I need to pass `dataa` and `mu_i` as parameters into the function within the apply function. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without using `apply` family of functions.  Try to take `transpose` of `dataa` and then divide by `mu_i`

```
  t(t(dataa)/mu_i) #returns a matrix output
  #          175       194       213       231       250
  #[1,] 1.0556274 1.0191865 1.1107078 0.9629187 1.1924290
  #[2,] 0.9883571 1.0498849 1.1179673 1.0215311 0.7854890
  #[3,] 1.0349288 0.8718342 1.0018149 0.9796651 1.0220820
  #[4,] 0.9935317 1.0805833 0.9509982 0.9712919 0.9652997
  #[5,] 0.9573092 1.0191865 0.9800363 1.0131579 1.0315457
  #[6,] 1.0142303 0.9884881 0.9219601 1.0717703 1.0031546
  #[7,] 0.9728331 0.9516500 0.9147005 0.9796651 0.0000000
  #[8,] 0.9831824 1.0191865 1.0018149 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Or

```
  dataa/mu_i[col(dataa)] #returns a data.frame output
  #       175       194       213       231       250
  #1 1.0556274 1.0191865 1.1107078 0.9629187 1.1924290
  #2 0.9883571 1.0498849 1.1179673 1.0215311 0.7854890
  #3 1.0349288 0.8718342 1.0018149 0.9796651 1.0220820
  #4 0.9935317 1.0805833 0.9509982 0.9712919 0.9652997
  #5 0.9573092 1.0191865 0.9800363 1.0131579 1.0315457
  #6 1.0142303 0.9884881 0.9219601 1.0717703 1.0031546
  #7 0.9728331 0.9516500 0.9147005 0.9796651 0.0000000
  #8 0.9831824 1.0191865 1.0018149 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Or if you need `apply` based solution

```
  mapply("/", dataa, mu_i) #returns a matrix
  #         175       194       213       231       250
  #[1,] 1.0556274 1.0191865 1.1107078 0.9629187 1.1924290
  #[2,] 0.9883571 1.0498849 1.1179673 1.0215311 0.7854890
  #[3,] 1.0349288 0.8718342 1.0018149 0.9796651 1.0220820
  #[4,] 0.9935317 1.0805833 0.9509982 0.9712919 0.9652997
  #[5,] 0.9573092 1.0191865 0.9800363 1.0131579 1.0315457
  #[6,] 1.0142303 0.9884881 0.9219601 1.0717703 1.0031546
  #[7,] 0.9728331 0.9516500 0.9147005 0.9796651 0.0000000
  #[8,] 0.9831824 1.0191865 1.0018149 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

If you need a `data.frame` output with `apply` based solution

```
  databa <- dataa
  databa[] <- Map("/", dataa, mu_i) #returns `data.frame`
```

Comment: I want to ask: how does the automatically mapply function know that I want to apply " divide by mu_i[i]" to each column of the data frame `dataa` ?

Comment: @Chinegro `mapply` applies the function elementwise.  In your example, `dataa` is a `data.frame`.  Each column is like individual list element.  `mu_i` is a vector, so it takes individual elements.  Try to do this by converting to `dataa` to a matrix.  You will find that for each element of the matrix, it will be divided by each element of mu_i and then it gets recycled.

Answer (score 5):

This is what `sweep` is for

```
sweep(dataa, 2, mu_i, "/")
```

Comment: This is preferential as it returns a `data.frame` back again rather than coercing to a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply`

```
sapply(1:5, function(i) dataa[,i]/mu_i[i])
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0556274 1.0191865 1.1107078 0.9629187 1.1924290
[2,] 0.9883571 1.0498849 1.1179673 1.0215311 0.7854890
[3,] 1.0349288 0.8718342 1.0018149 0.9796651 1.0220820
[4,] 0.9935317 1.0805833 0.9509982 0.9712919 0.9652997
[5,] 0.9573092 1.0191865 0.9800363 1.0131579 1.0315457
[6,] 1.0142303 0.9884881 0.9219601 1.0717703 1.0031546
[7,] 0.9728331 0.9516500 0.9147005 0.9796651 0.0000000
[8,] 0.9831824 1.0191865 1.0018149 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: you could generalize by using `seq_along(mu_i)` or `seq_along(dataa)` instead of `1:5`

Comment: I was trying to do this using the mapply function like this
`mapply(function(d,m,i)d[,i] - m[i],dataa,mu_i,seq_along(mu_i) )`. I don't understand why this failed. For some reasons, I need to pass `dataa` and `mu_i` as parameters into the function within the apply function. How would you do this ?

Comment: @Chinegro You could use `mapply('/', dataa, mu_i)`